# Very stupid navigation Godot 4.2.1

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

> I have a procedurally generated map that has resources with colliders (land does not have colliders). After generating resources on the stage, I bake a navigation polygon and I have, I don’t know how to say, “artifacts”, many very small polygons (there are also large ones). And when the navigation agent tries to pass through them, it creates incomprehensible paths.
> [image: Path example]

At first I thought it was a matter of resource's colliders, I had complex polygon colliders, I replaced them with simple squares -> Didn’t help

[image: Resourse Collider]

I tried changing the *path_desired_distance* parameter of *NavigationAgent2D*, but than the navigation agent began to pass through colliders

Then I decided to programmatically (not by hand) draw the polygon area -> it didn’t help

```
@onready var nav_mesh: NavigationRegion2D = $NavigationRegion2D
...

var nav_polygon: NavigationPolygon = NavigationPolygon.new()
    var bounding_outline = PackedVector2Array([Vector2(-SIZE.x * 32, -SIZE.y * 32), Vector2(SIZE.x * 32, -SIZE.y * 32), Vector2(SIZE.x * 32, SIZE.y * 32), Vector2(-SIZE.x * 32, SIZE.y * 32)])
    nav_polygon.add_outline(bounding_outline)
    nav_mesh.navigation_polygon = nav_polygon
```

I'm multiplying by 32 because the tilemap and global coordinates don't match

[image: All map]

Before this I worked with Unity and their NavMesh made the polygons larger. In general, please help me, give me options on what can be done, thanks.

Comment: decided on the [Godot Forum](https://forum.godotengine.org/t/very-stupid-pathfinding-godot-4-2-1/45170)